# save vertex groups as an image map for quick reskinning

Tags: weight-painting

Can blender save a vertex groups file as an image map which can be reused on different meshes? This is so there wouldn't be a need to do weight painting over and over if a large number of characters need to be skinned.

Comment: The characters would have to be exactly the same, or at least the same polycount and a comparable UV-layout...

Comment: Use the Data-transfer modifier to transfer vertex group data between meshes. Using textures places a need for correct UV unwrap, this way, you can use the projection method that is most suited.